# Can i use condition in inline style in angular like [style.height]="condition..."?

Tags: angular

i need to use a condition for giving style to my html tag inline,
is it right to do it like below:

```
[style.height.px]="booleanVar ? 11 + '!important' :7 + '!important'"
```

however i tested it and did not work, how fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use something like below,

```
[style.height]="booleanVar ? '11px' : '7px'"
```

for more about [style](https://blog.angulartraining.com/whats-the-difference-between-style-and-ngstyle-in-angular-68a3301c2ae6) check here once...

Comment: what about !important part because i think i need it?

Comment: i don't think it's required in every case.. until we have conflicts with some other property

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that is currently present in Angular. You cannot use `ngStyle` or `style` to set `!important`. Here's a [link to the open bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12009).

As a workaround until it's fixed, you can use `ngClass` instead. This is of course if you actually really need `!important` there in the first place.

```js
[ngClass]="booleanVar ? 'height-1': 'height-2'"
```

Then in your css

```css
.height-1 {
    height: 11px !important;
}

.height-2 {
    height: 7px !important;
}
```